# Why the surname 유 (Yoo) is translated as 刘 instead of 余 or 于？

Tags: translation, names, surnames

[유창혁](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%9C%A0%EC%B0%BD%ED%98%81) (Yoo Changhyuk) is translated as [刘昌赫](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%98%E6%98%8C%E8%B5%AB) in Chinese. Is there any reason that 유 is translated as 刘 instead of 余 or 于?

Comment: FYI: In South Korean dialects, if a word starts with **ry-** it gets shifted to **y-**, that is, the「ㄹ」sound gets omitted. So, in North Korea,「劉」is pronounced as「류」(**Ryoo**).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is *translated* as much as it is that every Korean family actually has their own *Hanja*.

According to Wikipedia's [List of South Korean surnames by prevalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_South_Korean_surnames_by_prevalence)

> 유

can be one of four Chinese characters:

> 柳, 劉, 兪, 庾

Most Koreans have Hanja names & they would certainly know which their surname is.

---

If you check out Wikipedia's [Appendix:Korean surnames](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Korean_surnames) you can see that

> 여

is the Southern Korean equivalent of

> 余

while

> 우

equates to

> 于, 禹

Answer (score 1):

[image: Korean newspaper, 1920]

Do you know what it is? It is a Korean newspaper printed in 1920. It is printed in Korean language, not Chinese. The Chinese characters in that newspaper are actually “Korean Chinese characters”, known as [hanja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanja) in English. Hanja is still the official script of Korean language, alongside Hangul.

Hanja has **not** been abolished in South Korea, but few Korean people use it today. Most of Korean people only write Hangul today, **except their names**. Korean names are still in Hanja.

**Have a look at South Korean identity cards. Korean names are still printed in Hanja.** As a result, we never translate Korean names into Chinese. We only copy the Chinese characters into Chinese.

---

Therefore, the real question should be:

Why is the Chinese character 刘 (劉) pronounced 유 (yoo) in Korean?